# переполнение базы данных sql server 2008 express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Развернут веб портал на Sherepoint 2010. База данных SQL Server 2008 Express.

Начал получать ошибку в журнале логов:

> Ошибка операции CREATE DATABASE или ALTER DATABASE, так как размер
>   результирующей совокупной базы данных превысил бы разрешенный предел в
>   4096 МБ на база данных.
>
> Не удалось выделить место для объекта "dbo.EventLog".'EventLog_Id' в
>   базе данных "DBNAME", поскольку файловая группа "PRIMARY"
>   переполнена. Выделите место на диске, удалив ненужные файлы или
>   объекты в файловой группе, добавив дополнительные файлы в файловую
>   группу или указав параметр автоматического увеличения размера для
>   существующих файлов в файловой группе.

Я бы удалил лишний контент но при удалении такие же ошибки. Понимаю что это связано с ограничением версии Express в 4Гб.

***Мой вопрос***: могу ли я просто обновить `Sql c SQL Server 2008 express` на `SQL Server 2008 R2 express`? Это решит проблему? Если возможно подскажите как, возможно есть подробная инструкция.

Спасибо.

Comment: в R2 лимит другой что ли сделали?

Comment: и правда до 10Гб подняли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете просто обновить, но рекомендую пользоваться инструкциями от майкрософта, в частности, проведите тестовое обновление перед основным, проверьте, что все функции вашего портала после обновления будут работать как нужно, что нет деградации производительности, и только после этого планируйте обновление основного сервера.

Подробные инструкции от Майкрософта по переходу на новую версию можно найти здесь:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267(v=sql.105).aspx